# How to change profile of Openshot project?

Tags: video, video-editor, editing

I stupidly started a project using a DVD NTSC profile, made a bunch of changes, and then realized that the final product is supposed to be DVD Widescreen NTSC. I can export it as such, but because I'm viewing the project in DVD NTSC, I can't tell how my changes will actually look in the final product.

Is it possible to change the profile of my project, so I can view it in DVD Widescreen NTSC while editing it?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the project
2. Goto File->Choose Profile
3. Select the profile you want
4. Save changes

`Note: checked with OpenShot 2.5.1`